# Заменить функцию в плагине на свою Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Написал дополнение для плагина, но одна из функций находится в самом плагине, что плохо, ведь обновление плагина все затрет. Можно ли переопределить pluginFunction() в functions.php, чтобы вместо нее использовалась моя?

Comment: Если функция не обернута в `if function_exist` то нельзя. Надо смотреть код, может,  там есть какие-то хуки.

Comment: Есть wp_create_user перед которым выполняется нужная обработка. Также есть add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_digits_submit_form', 'digits_process_form'), по сути можно сделать remove_action и добавить свою  функцию... Не знаете ли, function.php исполняется после инициализации плагинов?

Comment: Да, тема после инициализации плагинов

Comment: Спасибо большое!